# Error al instalar modulo Pyhook

Tags: python

Al usar el siguiente comando:

```
py ok.whl install
```

Obtengo este error:

> C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'ok.whl'

Comment: Puedes poner tu código, versión de python, sistema operativo, danos mas información para ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Como parece que tienes Python instalado de la forma estándar lo mejor es que descargues el ejecutable para instalar PyHook para tu versión de Python (2.7):

- [Aquí](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/files/pyhook/1.5.1/) tienes instaladores para Python2.7.

Para que funcione debes tener instalado también PyWin32.